# Units confusion while calculating flux of a star using distance and luminosity, Python

Tags: luminosity, units, flux

I am trying to calculate the flux of various stars in Python. I am using the information from a database containing all stars in Hipparcos, Yale Bright Star, and Gliese catalogs (almost 120,000 stars).

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sJGUxQpnsw93q48I1v8qo6rbDKCeGYOH/view?usp=sharing) is the database. The original source is [here](http://www.astronexus.com/hyg) and it is also [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/astronexus/HYG-Database).

The formula I am using to calculate the flux is 
$F=L/(4\pi d^2)$ where L is the luminosity and D is the distance.
In the database, the distance is provided in the 'dist' column and the luminosity is provided in the 'lum' column.

This is the code I used to calculate the flux data:

```
df["Flux"]=df['lum']/(4*np.pi*df['dist']**2)
df['Flux'].head(10)
```

And this is the output I received:

```
0     1.587863e-05
1     1.357072e-05
2     1.572559e-04
3     4.137163e-05
4     2.635442e-05
5     8.254667e-07
6     9.653330e-06
7     1.662834e-05
8     2.539475e-05
9     2.540078e-05
```

My question is:

- What is the unit of luminosity provided in the database?
- Are the calculated flux values correct in terms of units, or does it require a unit conversion?

Comment: Where did you get that database from? Otherwise you're just asking people to download a random file off Google Drive.

Comment: What are the units for each of these? Add the link requested above and check it for units.

Comment: @uhoh sorry for my late response. I got the database from this website: http://www.astronexus.com/hyg. It is the HYG 3.0 database from the website.

Comment: @DrishikaNadella Okay I've reversed my down vote to "up" and retracted my close vote, and added those links back to your original question. *Thanks for the reply!*

Comment: Have you read the catalogue information that tells you what each column is (and the units)? https://github.com/astronexus/HYG-Database

Comment: Looking at the Readme , I wonder how the table can be unclear... And how any answer here could give more info

Comment: As can be seen in the page given by Dr. Jeffries, luminosity units are in solar luminosities. Just for fun though I looked at the Gaia Data Release 2 info in the VizieR catalogue (accessed thru SIMBAD) for the first two stars HIP1 and HIP2. HIP2 is close, but HIP1 has a luminosity in HYG of 9.63 L(sun) and 6.263 L(sun) in VizieR.